# Can't link glfw with CMake in QtCreator in Ubuntu

Tags: c++, cmake, qt-creator, glfw

I'm trying to link glfw library to my project using cmake.
I use QtCreator 3.6 on elementary OS (Ubuntu 14.04).
Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>

int main() {

std::cout << "Hello World!" << std::endl;

if(!glfwInit()) {
    std::cout << "Error" << std::endl;
} else {
    std::cout << "Success" << std::endl;
}

glfwTerminate();

}
```

Here is my CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 2.8)
project (test)

add_library(glfw3 main.cpp)
include_directories("${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/glfw/include")
add_subdirectory(glfw)

add_executable(test main.cpp)
target_link_libraries (test glfw ${GLFW_LIBRARIES})
```

This code with this CMake file successfully compiles and runs through terminal (cmake/make/./test) but when I compile it in QtCreator I get a [lot of "undefined reference" errors](http://pastebin.com/0FCmXzaR).
I'll continue to search for the solution, but maybe someone can help me here.
Thank you.

Comment: "undefined reference" - means undefined references to external dynamic libraries (so, a, dll). Check out paths.

Comment: @AlexanderChernin sorry, I don't exactly understand you. What paths should I check? If I can compile my program through terminal, doesn't that mean all my paths are correct?

Comment: Path to glfw library in qtCreator's pro file.

Comment: @AlexanderChernin ok, well... I don't use qmake, I use cmake. Thanks anyways.

Comment: Sorry. Hard days... May be this help "Qt Creator detects the external libraries using the FIND_PACKAGE() macro. Some libraries come with the CMake installation. You can find those in the Modules directory of your CMake installation." from here http://doc.qt.io/qtcreator/creator-project-cmake.html

Comment: @AlexanderChernin I finally found the solution, I wrote my cmake file wrong, and you helped a lot. Spasibo.

Answer (score 3):

Here is my folder structure with GLFW, GLAD, CMAKE and QtCreator.

First install GLFW and dependencies from Repo:

```
sudo apt install cmake xorg-dev libglu1-mesa-dev libglfw3-dev libglfw3
```

OR

To build it

```
version="3.2.1" && \
wget "https://github.com/glfw/glfw/releases/download/${version}/glfw-${version}.zip" && \
unzip glfw-${version}.zip && \
cd glfw-${version} && \
sudo apt-get install cmake xorg-dev libglu1-mesa-dev && \
sudo cmake -G "Unix Makefiles" && \
sudo make && \
sudo make install
```

you can download glad from https://glad.dav1d.de/

My project Structure with glad:

```
test
  CMakeLists.txt
  source>main.cpp
  lib
    glad
      include>glad>glad.h
      src>glad.c
```

My Cmakelist:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)

project(test)

# Source files
set(SRC_DIR "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/source")
set(SOURCES "${SRC_DIR}/main.cpp")

# Executable definition and properties
add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} ${SOURCES})
target_include_directories(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE "${SRC_DIR}")
set_property(TARGET ${PROJECT_NAME} PROPERTY CXX_STANDARD 11)

TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(test -lglfw -lGL -lX11
    -lXi -lXrandr -lXxf86vm -lXinerama -lXcursor -lrt -lm -pthread)

# glad
set(GLAD_DIR "${LIB_DIR}lib/glad")
add_library("glad" "${GLAD_DIR}/src/glad.c")
target_include_directories("glad" PRIVATE "${GLAD_DIR}/include")
target_include_directories(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE "${GLAD_DIR}/include")
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} "glad" "${CMAKE_DL_LIBS}")
```

Test if everything is working:

```
#include <glad/glad.h>
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>

#include <stdio.h>

namespace {
   void errorCallback(int error, const char* description) {
      fprintf(stderr, "GLFW error %d: %s\n", error, description);
   }

   GLFWwindow* initialize() {
      int glfwInitRes = glfwInit();
      if (!glfwInitRes) {
         fprintf(stderr, "Unable to initialize GLFW\n");
         return nullptr;
      }

      glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3);
      glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 2);
      glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);
      glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_FORWARD_COMPAT, GL_TRUE);

      GLFWwindow* window = glfwCreateWindow(1280, 720, "InitGL", nullptr, nullptr);
      if (!window) {
         fprintf(stderr, "Unable to create GLFW window\n");
         glfwTerminate();
         return nullptr;
      }

      glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);

      int gladInitRes = gladLoadGL();
      if (!gladInitRes) {
         fprintf(stderr, "Unable to initialize glad\n");
         glfwDestroyWindow(window);
         glfwTerminate();
         return nullptr;
      }

      return window;
   }
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
   glfwSetErrorCallback(errorCallback);

   GLFWwindow* window = initialize();
   if (!window) {
      return 0;
   }

   // Set the clear color to a nice green
   glClearColor(0.15f, 0.6f, 0.4f, 1.0f);

   while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window)) {
      glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

      glfwSwapBuffers(window);
      glfwPollEvents();
   }

   glfwDestroyWindow(window);
   glfwTerminate();

   return 0;
}
```